# Fiegn Client not picking service url from Eureka Service

Tags: java, microservices, netflix-eureka, openfeign

I have just started with microservices and to learn I am working on [this project](https://github.com/dev-danish-javed/MicroServices)

The problem is although my services are registered at Eureka Server.
OpenFeing is not picking up the url. It is picking up the service name instead for the url.

###### The Problem

[image]

###### Check registered services

[image: Registed Services]

##### Application Properties

###### Server

```
server.port=8761

spring.application.name=eureka-server
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

###### Top layer (the one that'll consume other services)

```
spring.application.name=top-service
server.port=8080
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

###### Bottomlayer (the one that'll be consumed)

```
spring.application.name=bottom-service
server.port=8082
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

###### Open Feign Interface

```
@FeignClient(value = "bottom-service")
public interface AppFeignClient {
    @GetMapping
    public String test();

}
```

[Please checkout this github repo in case entire code is required](https://github.com/dev-danish-javed/MicroServices)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing path in my feign client. Updated that to

```
@FeignClient(value = "bottom-service", path = "/bottom")
public interface AppFeignClient {
    @GetMapping
    public String test();
}
```

Not it works fine. Although the url still uses the service name like but it is able to fetch data with the same url

[image]